# How to add recaptcha v2 invisible token to my ajax code

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I don't know how to add recaptcha's token to my ajax code. I can use `function onSubmit(token) {` but I don't know how to mix that with my ajax code. I tried alot, either I have to change my ajax code to `function onSubmit(token) {` or I add the token to my current Ajax Code. See code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#loginEmail').val();
        var loginSubmit = $('#loginSubmitButton').val();
        var password = $('#loginPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "login_ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { user_email:email,login:loginSubmit,user_password:password},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                if(data.type == 'success') {
                    $("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-success resizeFont' style='text-align:center;'>"+data.text+"</div>");
                } else if(data.type == 'error') {
                    $("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-danger resizeFont' style='text-align:center;'>"+data.text+"</div>");
                $('.hideForOtherMessage').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Can someone help me to add the Recaptcha token to this code instead of changing it to `function onSubmit(token) {`

This is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" class="recaptcha_form">
    <div id='message'></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>User Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="loginEmail" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style='margin-bottom:0px;'>
        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style='margin-bottom:1rem;'>
        <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin pwd" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button id="loginSubmitButton" type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary resizeButtonBeforeLogin g-recaptcha">Login</button>
    </div>
    <a href="reset-password.php" class='beforeLoginLinks'>Forgot your password?</a>
</form>
```

I tried to change my ajax code to `function onSubmit(token)` But i couldn't make it work with my existing AJAX code.

I tried adding `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()` to AJAX. Sometimes i get a recaptcha pop up to choose but nothing ever happens when i am finished with that.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $errors = [];

    include('config/database_connection.php');

    $secret="secret_key";
    $response=$_POST["captcha"];
    $verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
    
    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "ERROR YOU A ROBOT"));
        die($output);
    }
        else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'success', 'text' => "Success!"));
        die($output);
    }
?>
```

This doesn't work, can someone please help me, I am going crazy here.

**MY CODE WORKS NOW ONLY FOR THE STANDARD RECAPTCHA CODE BELOW (I WANT THE INVISIBLE VERSION)**

HTML:

```
                        <form method="post" id="loginForm" class="recaptcha_form">
                        <div id='message'></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>User Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="loginEmail" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style='margin-bottom:0px;'>
                        <label class='beforeLoginLabels'>Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" style='margin-bottom:1rem;'>
                            <input id="loginPassword" type="password" class="form-control cardBodyInputFieldBeforeLogin pwd" required />
    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id='review_recaptcha'></div>
                        <button id="loginSubmitButton" type="submit" name="login" data-sitekey="6LeMe3cpAAAAAC04MWEWqJNtHeu7QFkZvdfbOAr9" class="btn btn-primary resizeButtonBeforeLogin g-recaptcha">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <a href="reset-password.php" class='beforeLoginLinks'>Forgot your password?</a>
                        </form>
```

AJAX:

```
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
  grecaptcha.render("review_recaptcha", {
    "sitekey": "SITE_KEY"
  });
});


   $(document).ready(function(){ $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var email = $('#loginEmail').val();
     var loginSubmit = $('#loginSubmitButton').val();
     var password = $('#loginPassword').val();
     $.ajax({
       url: "recaptcha-test-ajax.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { user_email:email,login:loginSubmit,user_password:password,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {

         if(data.type == 'success') {
           $('#loginSubmitButton').html(
      "<span class='spinner-border spinner-border-sm' role='status' aria-hidden='true'></span> Laden..."
        );
           window.location='products.php';
      // alert("success");
         } else if(data.type == 'error') {
           $("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-danger resizeFont' style='text-align:center;'>"+data.text+"</div>");
           $('.hideForOtherMessage').hide();
           grecaptcha.reset();
         }
       }
     });
   });
   });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$errors = [];

include('config/database_connection.php');

$secret="SECRET_KEY";
$response=$_POST["captcha"];
$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

$filterCaptchCode = filter_var($response, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($filterCaptchCode)) {

        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "Please enter the reCAPTCHA"));
        die($output);
    }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
 if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM register_user
        WHERE user_email = :user_email
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
                'user_email'    =>  $_POST["user_email"]
            )
    );
    $no_of_row = $statement->rowCount();

    if($no_of_row > 0)
    {


        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {

                    if(password_verify($_POST["user_password"], $row["user_password"]))
                
                    {

                            $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'success', 'text' => 'SUCCESS'));

                die($output);
                    } else {
                        $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "Wrong password entered"));
                        die($output);
                    }
            }
        } else {
            $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "Wrong email entered"));
            die($output);
        }
  } else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => "ERROR YOU A ROBOT"));
    die($output);
  }

  $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'success', 'text' => "Success!"));
  die($output);
}
?>
```

I deleted some inrelevant code in this PHP code. So the brackets are not fully good closed i think. Don't mind that.

Comment: it is a long time since I looked at Google recaptcha but do you not need a hidden input in your form called `g-recaptcha-response`? Also, FYI, - you are incorrectly using `label` elements - they should be associated with input elements

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Can you please help me professor

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow :)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Oke thank you, i want it to be Recaptcha Invisible V2 please.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I managed to let the standard recaptcha V2 to work.  But i rather have the Invisible version. Hope you can help me tomorrow, i am going to sleep now, have a good sleep also. Bye bye

Comment: I uploaded the code that i am using for the standard V2 recaptcha mode. @ProfessorAbronsius Really am going to sleep now, bye bye

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might use an `invisible captcha` with vanilla Javascript and the `Fetch` api  - I don't use jQuery but you should be able to easily modify this to suit if you need.

```
<?php

    define('PUBKEY','xxxxxxx');
    define('PRIVKEY','xxxxxx');
    
    define('BASEURL','https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'],
        $_POST['email']
    )){
        if( !empty( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ){
            $url=sprintf(
                '%s?secret=%s&response=%s&remoteip=%s', 
                BASEURL, 
                PRIVKEY, 
                $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], 
                $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            );
            
            $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
            $data=false;
            
            if( $json->success==1 && $json->hostname==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
                # include <YOUR> database connection
                chdir('../../dbo');
                require 'db-conn-details.php';
                require 'pdo-conn.php';
                
                if( $db ){
                    
                    # whatever SQL command to auth user
                    $sql='select `password` from `users` where `email`=:email and `username`=:username';
                    $args=array(
                        ':email'    =>  $_POST['email'],
                        ':username' =>  $_POST['username']
                    );
                    
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->execute( $args );
                    $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
                    
                    if( $rs ){
                        
                        $pwdhash=$rs->password;
                        $authstatus=false;
                        
                        # do password_verify routines
                        if( password_verify( $_POST['password'], $pwdhash ) ){
                            $authstatus=true;
                            # set session variables etc
                            
                            
                            # this is only for demo.. send back whatever you need to
                            $data=array(
                                'user'          =>  $_POST['username'],
                                'captchastatus' =>  $json->success,
                                'authstatus'    =>  $authstatus,
                                'loggedin'      =>  true
                                
                            );
                        }
                        
                        header('Content-Type: application/json');
                        http_response_code( 200 );
                        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        http_response_code( 400 );
        exit();             
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Invisible Google reCaptcha - v2</title>
        <style>
            body{width:100%;height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center;overflow:hidden}
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;}
            form{display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:400px;padding:1rem;margin:auto;border:1px solid grey;border-radius:0.5rem;font-family:monospace}
            fieldset{border:none;width:100%;}
            legend{margin:1rem 0;font-size:1.25rem;background:grey;width:100%;padding:0.25rem;color:white}
            label{display:inline-flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between;width:100%;margin:0.25rem 0;}
            input,output{padding:0.25rem}
            .error{color:red;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='user'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <label>Email<input type='email' name='email' value='joe.bloggs@gmail.com' /></label>
                <label>Username<input type='text' name='username' value='Joe.Bloggs' /></label>
                <label>Password<input type='password' name='password' value='///twirls.faced.levels' /></label>
                
                <input type='button' value='Login' class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='<?=PUBKEY;?>' data-callback='authenticate' />
            </fieldset>
            <output></output>
        </form>
        
        
        
        
        <script>
            function authenticate(e){
                const output=document.querySelector('output');
                
                // success callback - do interesting things now user has logged in.
                // this just prints out name/value pairs sent back by php
                const callback=(res)=>{
                    if( res ){
                        output.innerHTML=Object.keys(res).map(key=>[key,res[key]].join('=')).join('<br />');
                        output.classList.remove('error')
                    }
                };
                
                // forward correct data type to callback
                const getdata=(res)=>{
                    if( res.status!=200 ){
                        output.textContent='Login Failed';
                        output.classList.add('error');
                    }
                    return res.headers.get('Content-Type')=='application/json' ? res.json() : res.text()
                };
                
                // things went wrong, panic
                const errhandler=(err)=>{
                    alert(err)
                };
                
                
                // php script to process login and authenticate captcha
                let url=location.href;
                
                // Fetch request config
                let args={
                    method:'post',
                    body:new FormData( document.forms.user )
                };
                
                // make the ajax request
                fetch(url,args)
                    .then(getdata)
                    .then(callback)
                    .catch(errhandler)
            }
        </script>
        <script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i can't use this code in mix with my own code. Also when i click  on login after the recaptcha finsished. I get 1606=o
1607=u
1608=t
1609=p
1610=u
1611=t
1612=>
1613=<
1614=/
1615=o
1616=u
1617=t
1618=p
1619=u
1620=t.

And more, what is this?

Comment: looks like the callback function is outputting something peculiar. hidden in that text it appears to say "output" but no doubt there is more that you have not shown. That callback, btw, is nonsense and NOT what you would use anyway - it was only there to show the actual ajax method and captcha process works